# Azure WebSite - Shared plan and SSL (aka. HTTPS)

Tags: azure, ssl, https

I wonder how exactly the https/ssl works on Azure when i have a shared plan. Microsoft states that i need at least basic plan to have SSL. When i try to access my site over "https://" protocol, apparently it works, and the browsers (I tested with Opera and Chrome) states that i have a secure connection.

Do you know how is this works? I have SSL even with shared plan, but it must be the certificate of the azurewebsites.net domain, and I just can't use my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On shared plan you can set a custom domain name but you cannot upload a custom SSL certificate. So you have to remain on the generic certificate *.azurewebsites.net that only matches yoursite.azurewebsites.net but not your custom domain name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Is this means my application still considered secure as long as I use the azurewebsites.net domain and https?

Comment: "secure" is a broad concept. If you use https for connecting to yoursite.azurewebsites.net, then your communication channel will be encrypted with TLS. No more, no less. :)